# Force index page on LAN connection

Tags: networking, lan, router

I run 3 servers on a local network. I'd like to force an index.html/php to pop on to anyone joining the LAN. I see many routers these days pop up a guest login page and think somehow I can point the router to my index.html/php so anyone joining the network is automatically shown the index without having to put an address in their browser. 
tia

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.wifidog.org/wiki/doc/install/ubuntu/auth-server

Here is one captive portal installation howto.

Hope that is what you are looking for.